# Admob Integration on project

Tags: android, admob

I want to add admob Service to my application then I will install application to Google Play. When I do testing process on emulator it works,coming test advertisement from admob, but then when I install application on google market doesn't come advertisement from admob.

When I use code like this it works:

```
  mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
  request = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("A65F386B8663703328FBEC25505E00B8").build();
  mAdView.loadAd(request);
```

but it is test advertisement I want to install application on Google Play and works there,When I use this code it doesn't show anything

```
  mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
  request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
  mAdView.loadAd(request);
```

My Xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/arkafon_second_screen"
     >




        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"


            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-4706271926046838/5956936636">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        >

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bttnzikir"
        android:text="Günlük Zikir Sayısı"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="...."
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20dp"

        android:id="@+id/txtzikir"

        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
    <Button
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bttnanlami"
        android:text="Zikir Niyeti"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        />


        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="....."
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20dp"

            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/txtanlami"
            />
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/bttnzikircek"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="Allah"
            android:textSize="45dp" />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtzikircek"
            android:layout_width="230dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_gonder"

            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="45dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/sifirla_btn"
            android:id="@+id/buttonreset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I do for the works application show the advertisement on the live device

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be fine. Recheck and double check the ad unit id in admob console.

Comment: Yes I checked  it same